# php Array key combination with sum of elements

Tags: php, arrays

```
Input:


  Array
(
[2] => 1
[7] => 1
[8] => 1
[9] => 2
)


 Output
  eg:
  [2] => 1
  [7] => 1
  [8] => 1
  [9] => 2
  [2_7] => 2 (sum of sf_2 and sf_7)
```

similar all possible combination of the given array
next like 2_7_8 (key) etc...
Basically combinations of given array elements...

Comment: the question is unclear, where did `sf_8` and `sf_9` come from?

Comment: sf_8 its a id of the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

essentially ... you add the base array `$base` to the result array `$result` until nothing changes anymore

```
$base = array( 2 => 1, 7 => 1, 8 => 1, 9 => 2 );
$results = $base;
$changed = true;
while($changed) {
    $changed = false;
    foreach($results as $id => $sum) {
        // which elements are included already?
        $contained = explode('_', $id);        
        foreach($base as $num => $value) {
            if(!in_array((string)$num, $contained)) {  
                // if current is not included, add
                $newid = array_merge($contained, [$num]);
                sort($newid); // optional, unless name must be sorted
                if(!isset($results[implode('_', $newid)])) {
                    // only add, if we don't already know that new element.
                    $results[implode('_', $newid)] = $sum + $value;
                    // set changed to true, so that another pass is made
                    $changed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is definitely not the best or most efficient method, but it's simple and it works.

if the key need not be sorted, `$results[$id.'_'.$num] = $sum + $value` would suffice, instead of `$newid` creation, sorting, and imploding.

**update**

if your base array has `n` elements, your result contains 2 to the power of `n` elements. if n is big enough, my naive implementation will take some time.

in that case a better solution would be:

```
$base = array( 2 => 1, 7 => 1, 8 => 1, 9 => 2 );
$sums = array();
$names = array();
$max = pow(2,count($base));
for($n=1; $n<$max; $n++)  {
    $sums[$n] = 0;
    $names[$n] = '';
    foreach(array_keys($base) as $index => $number) {
         $sums[$n] += ($n & pow(2,$index)) ? $base[$number] : 0;
         $names[$n] .= ($n & pow(2,$index)) ? '_'.$number : '';
    }
    $names[$n] = substr($names[$n], 1);
}
$result = array_combine($names, $sums);
```

Comment: well ... how many elements do you have in your base array? and do you really need all combinations?

Comment: @YabesNadar I updated my answer for a faster solution. also i found a bug in my old code ...

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there is a way around it... you'll need to split the key by `_` and sum all the `[sf_$k[$i]]` where `$k` is the split key and `$i` is bigger than 0 ( so that not to try to get `sf_sf` )